# How to access nltk using jython in Java

Tags: python, nltk, jython

Please help me understand how can I access NLTK using jython in java. I would like to use NLTK in Employee.py file in the example provided in below link.

https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/September2006/1

Comment: Please show what exactly you have trouble with. It's not clear what you don't understand, and the goal you want to achieve remains unclear and requires a lot of reading – you should assume no one is going to do that. Try to give a brief, precise description of your problem, such that an experienced user can quickly understand it and respond to it.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for not making it simple. I am trying to run Python code inside java program using Jython but I am confused how to import nltk to my python program here, It gives an exception "ImportError: No module named nltk". I would like to find a way to have it available in jython.